# What is Parent or Child product in Magento?

Tags: magento

What is Parent or Child product in Magento? Anyone can explain it to me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A product is called a `parent` product when it consists of one ore more different, but related items/products. In Magento, this usually is true for all products having a complex type, like

- `configurable` (parent: T-Shirt, children: red, green, blue (select one of x variants))
- `grouped` (parent: Pen box, children: red, green, blue (select qty for each color))
- `bundle` (parent: PC, children: mainboard, tower, harddisk, floppy (select a customized kit))

A `child` product in Magento often is of type `simple` (or `virtual` or `downloadable`) which belongs to one or more `parent` products.

See [Understanding product types](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/understanding-product-types) for more details on the different types.

Comment: Thanks for the information about magento products type